# Reinforcement Learning, ϵ-greedy approach vs optimal action

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In Reinforcement Learning, why should we select actions according to an ϵ-greedy approach rather than always selecting the optimal action ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming and rather belongs to Cross Validated (where there exists already a similar question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/270618/150976).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use an epsilon-greedy method for exploration during training. This means that when an action is selected by training, it is either chosen as the action with the highest Q-value, or a random action by some factor (epsilon).

Choosing between these two is random and based on the value of epsilon. initially, lots of random actions are taken which means we start by exploring the space, but as training progresses, more actions with the maximum q-values are taken and we gradually start giving less attention to actions with low Q-value.

During testing, we use this epsilon-greedy method, but with epsilon at a very low value, such that there is a strong bias towards exploitation over exploration, favoring choosing the action with the highest q-value over a random action. However, random actions are still sometimes chosen.

All this is because we want to eliminate the negative effects of over-fitting or under-fitting.

Using epsilon of 0 (always choosing the optimal action) is a fully exploitative choice. For example, consider a labyrinth game where the agent’s current Q-estimates are converged to the optimal policy except for one grid, where it greedily chooses to move toward a boundary (which is currently the optimal policy) that results in it remaining in the same grid, If the agent reaches any such state, and it is choosing the maximum Q-action, it will be stuck there. However, keeping a small epsilon factor in its policy allows it to get out of such states.

Comment: do you mean that if I'm still exploring then i can't choose the current optimal policy instead i should continue exploring till the final optimal policy ?

Comment: @AsmaaALrubia yes, basically you need the epsilon-greedy to get to the optimal policy

Answer (score 1):

There wouldn't be much learning happening if you already knew what the best action was, right ? :)

ϵ-greedy is "on-policy" learning, meaning that you are learning the optimal ϵ-greedy policy, while exploring with an ϵ-greedy policy. You can also learn "off-policy" by selecting moves that are not aligned to the policy that you are learning, an example is exploring always randomly (same as ϵ=1).

I know this can be confusing at first, how can you learn anything if you just move randomly? The key bit of knowledge here is that the policy that you learn is not defined by how you explore, but by how you calculate the sum of future rewards (in the case of regular Q-Learning it's the max(Q[next_state]) piece in the Q-Value update).

This all works assuming you are exploring enough, if you don't try out new actions the agents will never be able to figure out which ones are the best ones in the first place.